# discord.js awaitReactions filter to check if the user is in the same channel like bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

my filter doesn't work. I want, filter OUT if the bot reacts and if the channel isn't same as bot's, but it filters out all other reactions. If other member (without bot) is in the channel and probably isn't bot, it will filter out the reaction.

I hope you find what you need in my code, and help me :)

*pauseFalse(True)Reactions is array, serverQueue is JSON object, song is string*

```
var filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return pauseFalseReactions.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && message.guild.member(user.id).voice.channel == message.guild.member(botID).voice.channel && user.id != botID && user != bot.user;
};

awaitReact(message, filter, 1, Number(song.secs), pauseFalseReactions, serverQueue);

function awaitReact(message, filter, max, time, reactions, serverQueue) {
    message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: max, time: time, errors: ['time'] })
        .then(collected => {
            const reaction = collected.first();

            if (reaction.emoji.name == '⏸' && reactions.includes('⏸')) {

                Guild.findOneAndUpdate({ 
                    guildID: message.guild.id
                }, {
                    musicBotPaused: true,
                    musicBotPlaying: false
                }, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) { 
                        return console.error(err);
                    }
                });

                serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.pause();
                var newFilter = (reaction, user) => {
                    return pauseTrueReactions.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && message.guild.member(user.id).voice.channel == message.guild.member(botID).voice.channel && user.id != botID && user != bot.user;
                };
                message.reactions.removeAll().catch(error => console.error(error));
                addReactions(message, pauseTrueReactions);
                awaitReact(message, newFilter, max, (time + 250), pauseTrueReactions, serverQueue);

            } else if (reaction.emoji.name == '▶️' && reactions.includes('▶️')) {
                Guild.findOneAndUpdate({ 
                    guildID: message.guild.id
                }, {
                    musicBotPaused: false,
                    musicBotPlaying: true
                }, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) { 
                        return console.error(err);
                    }
                });

                serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.pause();
                var newFilter = (reaction, user) => {
                    return pauseFalseReactions.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && message.guild.member(user.id).voice.channel == message.guild.member(botID).voice.channel && user.id != botID && user != bot.user;
                };
                message.reactions.removeAll().catch(error => console.error(error));
                addReactions(message, pauseFalseReactions);
                awaitReact(message, newFilter, max, (time + 250), pauseFalseReactions, serverQueue);

            } else if (reaction.emoji.name == '⏭') {

                if (!serverQueue) {
                    const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor('#ff9745')
                        .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
                        .setAuthor('Zigger', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/app-icons/763859712340262972/010d590a764af0c59b999ad024cf89cb.png?size=128')
                        .setDescription('Ve frontě nic není.');
                    return message.channel.send(Embed);
                }

                message.channel.send(':fast_forward: **Přeskočeno** :thumbsup:');
                serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();

            } else if (reaction.emoji.name == '⏹') {

                if (serverQueue) {
                    serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
                    queue.delete(message.guild.id);
                }
                message.channel.send(':stop_button: **Zastaveno!** :thumbsup:');

            }
        })
        .catch(user => {

            if (user.id != botID || user != bot.user) {
                return;
            } else {
                message.reactions.removeAll().catch(error => console.error(error));
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will always be false:

```
message.guild.member(user.id).voice.channel == message.guild.member(botID).voice.channel
```

Use

```
message.guild.member(user.id).voice.channelID == message.guild.member(botID).voice.channelID
```

Comment: I changed that like you are saying, but the problem is still.